# Is there a "not allowed" character list for mysql table's column names?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I couldn't find anything on google, maybe I am not searching the correct term.
But is there a list of not allowed character for column names in mysql database ? I am particularly interested in the **$** sign.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: While mysql doesn't require `$` to be quoted, when working with PHP be aware of interpolation within strings and escape accordingly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Extracted from the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) assuming you are using at least MySQL 5.0 or higher:

Permitted characters in *unquoted* identifiers:

- ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
- Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

Permitted characters in *quoted* identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:

- ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
- Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

### TL;DR

Answering your question, yes.. You can use the `$` character in column names quoted or unquoted.